# Kernel of $\Bbb Z/2^k\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Just to be sure I'm not an idiot, the kernel of $$\Bbb Z/2^k\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\\ 1\mapsto 1$$ is $\Bbb Z/2^{k-1}\Bbb Z$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. If I am being pedantic, then no. However, the kernel is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb Z/2^{k-1}\Bbb Z$. The kernel should be written as $\langle 2\rangle$ to emphasize that it's a *subgroup* of the domain, and not a group existing on its own right without being part of something bigger.

> (At least until you get to category theory, where kernels truly are their own, separate objects, together with a homomorphism which emulates the "inclusion" you're used to. But then they are also defined not uniquely, but "up to unique isomorphism".)

Comment: Even in category theory, kernels are ***not*** on their own - a kernel is an object *together* with a morphism.

Comment: @lisyarus True, but that was not the contrast I wished to make. The object itself exists more independently in category thoeory than in standard group theory. Still, I added the correction.

Comment: I would argue that they are not much more independent. Anyway, the concept of *defined up to an isomorphism* is one that is important here, not the fact that kernels are separate objects (again, because this is just a point of view, like a subset or a set + injection as a subset).

Comment: @lisyarus In group theory a kernel is specifically defined as a group that has as elements a subset of the elements of the original group. In category thoeory, the elements can be whatever they want, as long as the corresponding morphisms exists. Since that means that exactly what the elements of the original group are has no effect on what the elements of the kernel can be, I would call it "more independent".

Comment: I see. I was just amazingly disturbed with the phrase "truly are their own" :)

Comment: @lisyarus I'm probably being not very precise, but here is an example of what I'm thinking of: Take $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. The group kernel necessarily has real numbers (for instance Dedekind cuts over the dyadics or rationals) as elements, while you can take the _actual integers_ (however you define those), or the corresponding subset of the rationals, or the corresponding subset of the reals, or any other isomorphic structure to be the category theoretic kernel.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I like the answer, specifically the note that kernel is *not* $\mathbb{Z}/2^{k-1}\mathbb{Z}$, but isomorphic to it. I just wanted to emphasize that in category-theoretic setting things are more or less the same, but much more explicit: now kernel is anything satisfying some property, not just a distinguished subset.